# Why does container fill up the entire space?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm having a hard time understanding the following [example from the official Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints#:%7E:text=paints%20it%20red.-,Example%202,-content_copy):

[image]

Following the famous ["Constraints go down. Sizes go up. Parent sets position"](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints#:%7E:text=Constraints%20go%20down.%20Sizes%20go%20up.%20Parent%20sets%20position.) rule and assuming the screen size is `1024x800` shouldn't the conversation between the widgets look like this:

> Parent: "You must be from `0` to `1024` pixels wide and `0` to `800` pixels tall".
>
> Child (the red container): "Ok. I want to be `100` pixels wide and `100` pixels tall".

According to the docs, however, the parent is forcing the child to occupy the entire screen.

So why does it do this instead of letting the child be `100x100`?

Comment: if you don't specify the container width height, it automatically takes parent width height, in this case screen width height. did you got it?

Comment: @ThusithaDeepal The container clearly has both `width` and `height` set to 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per my knowledge, when we are talk about constrains, there are 2 mandatory fields.

- Size
- Position

and also its has mentioned on documentation. there are some limitations

> - widget usually can’t have any size it wants.
> - widget can’t know and doesn’t decide its own position in the screen

in **Example 2**, as you mentioned, the container only has **Size** , but doesn't know where it is on the screen. that's why  the Container fills the screen.

---

by adding `Aligment` will set the position of the container. thats why in example 3 , when its wraped with `Center` the size = 100x100

because now the container has 2 mandatory fields:

- Size : 100x100
- Position : in the center of the screen ( `Alignment.center` )

Answer (score 1):

In the Limitations section, the doc says :

> If a child wants a different size from its parent and the parent
> doesn’t have enough information to align it, then the child’s size
> might be ignored. Be specific when defining alignment.

It mean that if you only provide Size but don't have Position, then the Size of child will be ignored